# Python Selenium: Firefox set_preference to overwrite files on download?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using these Firefox preference setting for `selenium` in Python 2.7:

```
ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_dir)

ff_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
ff_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
ff_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", dl_dir)
ff_profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")
```

With Selenium, I want to recurringly download the same file, and overwrite it, thus keeping the same filename – without me having to confirm the download.

With the settings above, it will download without asking for location, but all downloads will creates duplicates with the filename `filename (1).ext`, `filename (2).ext` etc in MacOS.

I'm guessing there might not be a setting to allow overwriting from within Firefox, to prevent accidents(?).

(In that case, I suppose the solution would be to handle the overwriting on the disk with other Python modules;  another topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that is *out of the Selenium's scope* and is handled by the operating system.

Judging by the context of this and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39519518/771848), you know (or can determine from the link text) the filename beforehand. If this is really the case, before hitting the "download" link, make sure you remove the existing file:

```
import os

filename = "All-tradable-ETFs-ETCs-and-ETNs.xlsx"  # or extract it dynamically from the link
filepath = os.path.join(dl_dir, filename)
if os.path.exists(filepath):
    os.remove(filepath)
```

Comment: With headless settings turned on, in order to get downloads working, there is a setting required,
    Dictionary<string, object> Params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Params["behavior"] = "allow";
    Params["downloadPath"] = downloadDir;
    driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", Params);
And the major problem I'm finding is the exact behavior stated above is happening. Except, I want the default OS\Windows\default browser behavior. How can I get it back?